# Directshow Virtual Webcam video is greyscale on certain conference apps

Tags: c++, video-streaming, video-processing, directshow, virtual-webcam

I have built a virtual webcam DirectShow filter in C++.

Everything on it is working well and looks great on Zoom and Microsoft Teams, however, on Webex and Whereby, the image is coming through greyscale with small auras of color here and there. I checked the resolution and that does not seem to effect the color.

I do find it odd that it is on specific platforms where this happens. I am converting the video to NV12 format when sending frames to the virtual camera. Is there another format that I should consider if the user is using one of these platforms?

I have checked the resolution of the video, tested with multiple video conference platforms, and checked the raw video in graphEdit and graphStudio. I did check to make sure the UV values were being sent to the camera as well.

In terms of the camera it is working correct, it is just when those platforms access my virtual webcam.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!